# Pandas; Trying to split a string in a column with | , and then list all strings, removing all duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, multiple-columns

I'm working on a data frame for a made up TV show. In this dataframe, are columns: "Season","EpisodeTitle","About","Ratings","Votes","Viewership","Duration","Date","GuestStars",Director","Writers", With rows listed as ascending numerical values.

In this data frame, my problem relates to two columns; 'Writers' and 'Viewership'. In the Writers column, some of the columns have multiple writers, separated with " | ". In the Viewership column, each column has a float value between 1 and 23, with a max of 2 decimal places.

Here's a condensed example of the data frame I'm working with. I am trying to filter the "Writers" column, and then determine the total average viewership for each individual writer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Writers' : ['John Doe','Jennifer Hopkins | John Doe','Ginny Alvera','Binny Glasglow | Jennifer Hopkins','Jennifer Hopkins','Sam Write','Lawrence Fieldings | Ginny Alvera | John Doe','John Doe'], 'Viewership' : '3.4','5.26','22.82','13.5','4.45','7.44','9'})
```

The solution I came up with to split the column strings:

```
df["Writers"]= df["Writers"].str.split('|', expand=False)
```

This does split the string, but in some cases will leave whitespace before and after commas. I need the whitespace removed, and then I need to list all writers, but only list each writer once.

Second, for each individual writer, I would like to have columns stating their **total average viewership**, or a list of each writer, stating what their **total average viewership** was for all episodes they worked on:

`["John Doe : 15" , "Jennifer Hopkins : 7.54" , "Lawrence Fieldings : 3.7"]`

This is my first post here, I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# I believe in newer versions of pandas you can split cells to multiple rows like this
# here is a reference https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#series-explode-to-split-list-like-values-to-rows

df2 =df.assign(Writers=df.Writers.str.split('|')).explode('Writers').reset_index(drop=True)

#to remove whitespaces just use this
#this will remove white spaces at the beginning and end of every cell in that column
df2['Writers'] = df2['Writers'].str.strip()

#if you want to remove duplicates, then do a groupby
# this will combine (sum) duplicate, you can use any other mathematical aggregation
# function as well (you can replace sum() by mean())
df2.groupby(['writers']).sum()
```

Comment: Hey Ahmed! I appreciate your insight. I have tried using the .strip() method to remove whitespace, however, since it only removes whitespace at the beginning and end of each cell, I still am left with my writers column containing multiple writers in a single string, with whitespace, too. In my example above, I have episodes worked on by a single writer, and others worked on by multiple writers. Ex: ["John Doe", "John Doe | Jennifer Hopkins"]. I am needing to separate the writers individually, and then figure out their total average viewership for all the episodes that writer has worked on.

Comment: you want to split the writer column to multiple rows? I will update my answer

Comment: Ahmed, this was extremely helpful. Thank you so much. I do have another request if you have time to answer. So now with df2, is there a way to throw out all the columns I do not need for my solution? I'm only needing to carry over the "Writers" and "Viewership" columns, with their respected data values. In your solution, it carries over all data. Is there a way to condense what is transferred to df2? Thanks!

Comment: you means something like this? del df2['columnName'] ?

Comment: if you want to drop multiple columns use this 
df2.drop(['c1', 'c2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
... If you found my answer helpful, do you mind if you accept it as the correct answer?

Comment: Awesome, done and works. So now, when I do df2.groupby(["Writers"]).mean(), it will list all the writers, but I'm getting a lot of duplicate writers. When I make a print statement, it will show a list of writers, lots of which are duplicates, their viewership, but it's not getting me the mean of their viewership, and condensing the writers, only giving me one average value for each writer. Would you know why this is happening?

Comment: I am not sure if I follow but try this
df2.drop_duplicates(['writers', 'Viewership'])

Comment: Hi Ahmed. I think I found my problem. Do you have time to edit your answer? I think when I invoke the .assign() method, it carries over white space in the writers column. The split method works, but it is leaving behind whitespace in my "Writers" columns after splitting, making it unable to find a mean of viewership, since it cannot distinguish "John doe" from "John Doe(whitespace) " or " (whitespace) John Doe"

Comment: you can run the df2['Writers'] = df2['Writers'].str.strip() to remove white spaces. let me know if you couldn't resolve it.